# What is wrong in calling procedure from c++ DLL

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I have a simple DLL in c++ builder.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdreason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    return TRUE;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  void show_m(void)
{
 MessageBox(NULL, "MSG", "COTI DLL", MB_OK |MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

When I call this in delphi I get error that there is no procedure in dll:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DLL : THandle;
  show_m1 : procedure; cdecl;

begin
    DLL := LoadLibrary('mylib.dll');
    @show_m1:= GetProcAddress(DLL, 'show_m');
    show_m1;
    FreeLibrary(DLL);
end;
```

What is wrong, It shoud be working correct but it is not?

Comment: Could you use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to check mylib.dll's exports?

Comment: What should I see in that, because I open there dll which is 100% working and this which is not working and both of them looks the same in this tool?

Comment: When you select your library in the list to the left, you should see the exports defined in the library on the right.  If possible using whatever debugger at your disposal (I'm completely unfamiliar with Delphi), check to see what mylib.dll's path was when it loaded into the process; perhaps it's finding an incorrect mylib.dll?

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly give a *there is no procedure in dll* error, what it should cause is an AV. Since you don't check the return of LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress, you'd call an unassigned procedure if the dll does not have the procedure.

Comment: Don't use `THandle` for the return value of `LoadLibrary`. It's not a `THandle`. It's an `HMODULE`. Checking for errors would be a good move, as Sertac says.

Comment: I solved it must defined in dll:
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall void show_m(void)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in Delphi, Win32 API handles are best declared as `THandle`.  In fact, `Windows.HMODULE` is just a typedef for `THandle`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In Win32 there are lots of different types of handles. You cannot pass an `HMODULE` to `CloseHandle` for example. So no, don't call everything `THandle`. It would actually matter if the Delphi header translation would use some strict typing. Pretending that all of these windows types are actually just NativeInt is not helpful. Anyway, it's a matter of fact that `LoadLibrary` returns `HMODULE`. I prefer not to be sloppy.

Answer (score 7):

You already discovered the solution: add the `__stdcall` calling convention.  The reason why it works is because the original code did not specify a calling convention, so `__cdecl` gets used instead.  When using `extern "C"`, the `__cdecl` calling convention exports the function name as `"_show_m"` (unless you use a .def file to change that), which is why `GetProcAddress()` does not find it.  When using `__stdcall` instead, the exported function name is `"show_m"` as expected.  Don't forget to change your Delphi code to use `stdcall` instead of `cdecl` for your `show_m1` variable:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdreason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    return TRUE;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall show_m(void)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "MSG", "COTI DLL", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DLL : THandle;
  show_m1 : procedure; stdcall;
begin
  DLL := LoadLibrary('mylib.dll');
  if DLL <> 0 then
  try
    @show_m1 := GetProcAddress(DLL, 'show_m');
    if Assigned(show_m1) then
      show_m1;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(DLL);
  end;
end;
```